# Given a Map with values of type string, which are all numbers separated by commas, would it be possible to transform each value into a double?

Tags: java, string, list, hashmap, double

I recently asked about converting Json using Gson into something I can sort values into, and the best option was using a Linked HashMap.

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(tm.split("  |,")); // split into pair key : value
    Map<String, List<String>> mapString = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    stringList.forEach(s1 -> {
                String[] splitedStrings = s1.split(": "); //split into key : value
                String key = splitedStrings[0].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]",""); // remove non alphanumeric from key, like {
                String value = splitedStrings[1];
                if (mapString.get(key) == null) {
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
                    values.add(value);
                    mapString.put(key, values);
                }else if (mapString.get(key) != null) {
                    mapString.get(key).add(value);
                }
            });
```

When this code is run, a map with keys for frequency, magnitude, and other attributes of my data is created. This is the original Json Message compared to the resulting map value for the same set of data (Formatted to make it easier to understand and look better)

```
 {"groupId":"id3_x_","timestamp":1.591712740507E9,"tones": 
   [{"frequency":1.074,"level":3.455,"bw":0.34,"snr":3.94,"median":0.877}, 
   {"frequency":14.453,"level":2.656,"bw":0.391,"snr":2.324,"median":1.143}, 
   {"frequency":24.902,"level":0.269,"bw":0.282,"snr":2.216,"median":0.121}, 
   {"frequency":22.607,"level":0.375,"bw":0.424,"snr":2.034,"median":0.184}, 
   {"frequency":9.863,"level":2.642,"bw":0.423,"snr":1.92,"median":1.376}]}
```

To Map values:

```
Message Received  
Group ID:         id3_x_
Message Topic:    pi7/digest/tonals
Time of Arrival:  1.591712740507E9
---------------DATA---------------
Frequency: [1.07, 14.45, 24.90, 22.61, 9.86]
Magnitude: [3.46, 2.66, 0.27, 0.38, 2.64]
Bandwidth: [0.34, 0.39, 0.28, 0.42, 0.42]
SNR: [3.94, 2.32, 2.22, 2.03, 1.92]
Median: [0.88, 1.14, 0.12, 0.18, 1.38]]
```

While this is very useful for analyzing the data, the information stored is a string. What I would like to be able to do is transform each of the values in the map (Example: Frequency 1.07, 14.45, etc.) into doubles that i can then run through additional programs and run calculations with, such as an average. I have looked around online and havnt found anything that I am looking for, so im wondering if there would be a way to transform these strings into doubles using either an array, list, or any other means.

I am an intern for a tech company so I am still trying to hammer in Java and describing what I am talking about, so if there is any questions about what I am asking, please let me know and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could get a Map from the JSON file , you can also extract the values array from the Map `yourmap.getvalues()` , then you can parse each on of these element and case it into double

---

*Example : Frequency: [1.07, 14.45, 24.90, 22.61, 9.86]*

```
for ( String f : Frequency ) {
    double f_double = Double.parse(f); // turns String into double
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with another class that will store duplicate attribute values in arrays. You can simply get them through a.getValues (). This is just a concept and you should extend it as it will be convenient for you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Attribute>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
        attributes.add(new Attribute("frequency", 3.46, 5.11, 6.12));
        attributes.add(new Attribute("magnitude", 3.46, 10.22, 10.54));
        //and so on

        map.put("idString1", attributes);

        //printing double values
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {

            for (Attribute a : map.get(key)) {
                System.out.println(a.getName() + " " +Arrays.toString(a.getValues()));
                //a.getValues() to get all of doubles
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Attribute {

        private String name;
        private double[] values;

        Attribute(String name, double... values) {
            this.name = name;
            this.values = values;
        }

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        double[] getValues() {
            return values;
        }
    }

}
```

The result will be:

```
frequency [3.46, 5.11, 6.12]
magnitude [3.46, 10.22, 10.54]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> I would like to be able to do is transform each of the `String` values in the
>   map (Example: Frequency 1.07, 14.45, etc.) into doubles and run calculations with, such as an average.

Yes, it is possible to transform your `String` array in a `double` array using `Stream` like below:

```
String[] frequencies = { "1.07", "14.45", "24.90", "22.61", "9.86" };
double[] arr = Stream.of(frequencies)
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .toArray();
```

If you use the `DoubleSummaryStatistics` class you have already available ops like avg, sum :

```
String[] frequencies = { "1.07", "14.45", "24.90", "22.61", "9.86" };
DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = Stream.of(frequencies)
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        .summaryStatistics();
System.out.println(statistics.getAverage()); //<-- 14.578
System.out.println(statistics.getMax()); //<-- 24.9
```